# Isn't Careers supposed to prevent recruiter spamming?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I just got a contact request through careers.  There wasn't a single point of intersection between the skill set they were looking for and the skills I advertise, and in spite of the fact that I didn't check the "willing to relocate" button, this job is a thousand miles away from my home.

How exactly is careers going to differentiate itself from Monster if recruiters are allowed to spam every warm body on the site?

Comment: careers should allow job seekers to downvote recruiters.

Comment: @Ether This is implemented, but more like flagging than downvoting.  When you mark a message as "Not Interested", you can indicate why, and we keep an eye on those.

Comment: @DavidFullerton that only works if the recruiter reveals their location in the inital message; if it's later inthe thread there's no way to go back and mark the thread 'Not Interested'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While there's nothing that prevents people from sending a spammy message, we did recently start to collect responses from people that mark a message as "not interested". In your case  that would be: "This position does not appeal to my interests at all". We use this feedback as a quality indicator, and will take action if we see that an employer is abusing the service, up to and including refunding and canceling their subscription (although that would be a final measure, we'd much rather have them see the light and start sending well targeted and interesting messages). Over time we'll work to fine tune this quality feed back mechanism.

Also, forwarding a spammy message to careers@stackoverflow.com is a good way to get us to look at it.

W/r/t the message you received, we'll look into this employer to see how their messages have been received. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: To repeat my previous comment: The 'Not Interested' bit only works if you're able to tell before first response that the job is unsuitable.  In my case, I didn't notice the job was far away before replying, so there's no way to flag the thread anymore.

Answer (score 3):

We also cap the number of open messages to candidates (messages without a response) at 20.  So they can't really spam the entire database effectively.

Comment: So what you're saying is we shouldn't respond to these messages, and then they'll eventually run out of open messages so they'll be unable to spam anybody else?

Comment: @Paul:  Nah, we don't need the candidates "gaming" our system to try and screw spammers.  When you respond not interested you get to choose a reason (never sent to the employer, we just use the reasons internally) and you should choose "This position does not appeal to my interests at all".  We'll be watching :)

Comment: The "not interested" doesn't go to the employer?  The link is labelled "Reply to employer", which kind of gives the opposite impression.

Comment: @Paul: The "not interested" goes to the employer, but the sub-section labeled "Why are you not interested? (for internal use only, never seen by employer)" does not go to the employer.  So they know you weren't interested, but not why.